# MySQL split single column

Tags: mysql

I thought this would be easy... maybe not. I have a table with 'fullname' and I want to split the first name and last name into 2 columns (fname and lname).

The following syntax gives me the data I want:

```
SELECT 
`fullname` , 
SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(`fullname` ,' ', 2) ,' ' ,-1) AS fname, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(`fullname` ,' ', 1)AS lname
FROM MyTable
```

... but how do I then take the 'fname' and 'lname' fields and save them to separate columns in the same table?

[Example data -- If the persons name is John Michael Jones, the 'fullname' field looks like this: JONES JOHN MICHAEL ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just update your table and set the columns to the substrings of the `fullname`

```
update MyTable
set fname = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`fullname` ,' ', 2) ,' ' ,-1),
    lname = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`fullname` ,' ', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform the update on the same table, you can use the following:

```
update mytable
set fname = SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(`fullname` ,' ', 2) ,' ' ,-1), 
  lname = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`fullname` ,' ', 1)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c7bc/1)

Answer (score 0):

you want to update into first name ans last name value then you need to used update :

```
update MyTable
set fname = SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(`fullname` ,' ', 2) ,' ' ,-1), 
  lname = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`fullname` ,' ', 1)
```

and if you want to set in upper case then user upper function as well as

```
 update MyTable
    set fname = upper(SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(`fullname` ,' ', 2) ,' ' ,-1)), 
      lname = upper(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`fullname` ,' ', 1))
```